# Rerun failed tests using resharper v10

Tags: unit-testing, resharper

It used to be that I could rerun all failed tests in a resharper unit test session by showing only the failed tests, right clicking the root node, and selecting "Create New Session". Somewhere along the version updates, this functionality got lost.

Is there a way to rerun the failed unit tests from the resharper unit test sessions window?

Comment: Come on, JetBrains, fix this!

Answer (score 3):

There is a R# bug describing this issue: [RSRP-442481](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-442481). Although this issue tracker entry is "fixed", the bug still seems to exist. I've reproduced it in R# 10.0.2 and 10.1 EAP 7 (see my [comment in the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-442481#comment=27-1372041)).